# Substring contatining words up to n characters

Tags: java, string, substring

I've got a string and I want to get first words that are containing up to N characters together.

For example:

`String s = "This is some text form which I want to get some first words";`

Let's say that I want to get words up to 30 characters, result should look like this:

`This is some text form which`

Is there any method for this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

EDIT: I know the substring method, but it can break words. I don't want to get something like

`This is some text form whi`
etc.

Comment: use `String#substring(.,.)`

Comment: Yes, there is a method called `substring()` Please Google.

Comment: Substring is breaking the words, I don't want to get something like `This is some text form wh` etc.

Comment: do substring and join by white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to achieve this. Something like below should do the job:

```
    String input = "This is some text form which I want to get some first words";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\b.{25}[^\\s]*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

This yields:

```
This is some text form which
```

An explanation of the regular expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/iI2oT6/1). I used 25 since the first 25 characters would result into a broken sub string, so you can replace it with whatever value you want.

Comment: `[^\\s]` can be written as `\\S`. Also I am not sure about `+`, `*` feels better IMO.

Comment: @Pshemo: I agree on the `*` and `+`. I tend to prefer `[^\s]` simply because I think it makes it slightly easier to read.

Comment: True, `[^\s]` may be easier to read, but `\S` is easier to write :)

Comment: @Pshemo: There is nothing easy about regex :P

Comment: I didn't say easy, but easier :D

Comment: @Pshemo: You got me there.

Answer (score 1):

Split your string with space ' ' then foreach substring add it to a new string and check whether the length of the new substring exceeds or not exceeds the limit.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to implement it, but i thought that such method already exists somewhere so i could reuse it

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this without regex

```
String s = "This is some text form which I want to get some first words";
// Check if last character is a whitespace
int index = s.indexOf(' ', 29-1);
System.out.println(s.substring(0,index));
```

The output is `This is some text form which`;

obligatory edit: there is no length check in there, so care for it.